# How to tell if a function is one-to-one or onto

Tags: functions

We just learnt this today in Discrete Math, and now I'm trying to review from the textbook. However unfortunately during this lecture I was completely lost with no idea what was going on.

I know that for one-to-one, every $x$ has an unique $y$ and for onto, for all $y$ there exists an $x$ such that $f(x)=y$.

I've provided two questions to use as examples from my textbook.

1. Suppose $f \colon \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ has the rule $f(n) = 4n + 1$. Function $f$ is one-to-one.
2. Suppose $f \colon \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ has the rule $f(n) = 3n - 1$. Function $f$ is onto $\Bbb Z$.

Answer one or both or give a hint, I would just love any explanation to what is going on! Thanks!

Comment: See if it passes the Vertical Line Test AND the Horizontal Line Test. If so, that function is 1-1. Ex: $y = x^3$

Comment: In fact, the definition of a function requires $x$ to have a unique $y$ whenever $f: X \to Y$.

Comment: @DonLarynx As much I appreciate hints, we have not learnt that so I have no idea what that is.

Comment: @DonLarynx I don't understand your hint. How does the notion of cardinality help with this question?

Comment: The way to identify a duck goes like this: 0) know what makes a duck a duck 1) look at something 2) decide if it has all the properties of a duck. 3) Say yes/no accordingly 4) Done. The procedure with "duck" swapped with "onto function" or "1-1 function" is the same. Is your trouble at step 2 or 0?

Comment: Between ducks and cardinals, I hope we haven't confused the OP   :)  He might think we're birdbrains....

Comment: @DonLarynx, your hint doesn't seem to have anything to do with anything.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1) Let's show this function is $1-1$. To do this, we suppose $f(n_1) = f(n_2)$ and show that this forces $n_1 = n_2$.

So, if it's true that $f(n_1) = f(n_2)$, then this means that

$$4n_1 + 1 = 4n_2 + 1 \\
\Rightarrow 4n_1 = 4n_2 \\
\Rightarrow n_1 = n_2 $$

and we have demonstrated what is required. Thus, $f$ is $1-1$.

2) Let's see if the function is onto (it might not be). If it is, we should be able to choose **any** $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and show that there is some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(n) = 3n - 1 = m$.

If this is true, then we will need $n = \dfrac{1}{3}(m + 1)$. The problem is that this might not be an integer! For example, if $m = 1$, then $n$ would need to be $\dfrac{2}{3}$, which is not an integer. Thus, there is no $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(n) = 1$ and so the function is **not** onto.

**EDIT**: For fun, let's see if the function in 1) is onto. If so, then for every $m \in \mathbb{N}$, there is $n$ so that $4n + 1 = m$. For basically the same reasons as in part 2), you can argue that this function is **not** onto.

For a more subtle example, let's examine

3) $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ has the rule $f(n) = n + 2$. If it is onto, then, for every natural number $m$, there is an $n$ such that $n + 2 = m$; i.e. that $n = m - 2$. Now, we don't have the same problem as we did before, that is, we don't have to divide by anything to solve for $n$. Thus there is always an *integer* $n$ so that $n + 2 = m$.

BUT! If $m = 1$ (for example), then $n$ would have to be $1 - 2 = -1$ which is **not** a natural number, so this function is **not** onto either.

The point of all this is, we have to look closely at both the domain and codomain to answer these kinds of questions.

Comment: Ok, so I'm starting to see the light. But let's take "1)" if we changed the last sentence to "function is onto N" that would be 'False' since the function is 1-1. Unless it could be both?

Comment: @user7349: Yes, a function can be both one-to-one and onto. We call this a bijection; a fancy name for an invertible function.

Comment: A function can be $1-1$ *and* onto (or it can be one, but not the other, or it can be neither). I'll edit in a discussion of whether the function in 1) in onto.

Comment: Ok, so you're awesome! (for going beyond my original question) and your explanation(s) are great, thank you! (the fog as lifted)

Comment: fantastic explanation

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show that a function, say $f$, is 1-to-1, then you typically consider two values $x_1,x_2$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. From this, if you can derive that $x_1=x_2$, then your function is 1-to-1.

Let's consider your first example. We would have $f(x_1)=4x_1+1=4x_2+1=f(x_2)$. We can then simplify to obtain $x_1=x_2$. Hence $f$ is 1-to-1.

To show that a function $f$ is not 1-to-1, it suffices to find $x_1,x_2$ in the domain of $f$ such that $x_1\neq x_2$, but $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

If you want to show that a function $f$ is onto, then for any $y$ in the image/range of $f$, you must find $x$ in the domain such that $f(x)=y$.

To show that a function $f$ is not onto, just find $y$ in the target set of $f$ (that is, the set at the end of your arrow $f:X\to Y$; we call it the *codomain*) such that there is no $x$ in the domain such that $f(x)=y$.

As Baron pointed out, the function in your second example is not onto... we'll show this as an example that something is not onto. Consider any $y\in\mathbb Z$. In order for $f$ to be onto, there must be an $x$ such that $f(x)=3x-1=y$, or 
$$
x = \frac{y+1}{3}.
$$
Now, we can see that $x$ is not an integer (as required) for some values of $y$. Namely, if $y=1,3,4,6,$etc., then there is no $x$ such that $f(x)=y$. Thus $f$ cannot be onto.

Answer (score 2):

1. Another option: decompose $f$ into simpler functions that are easier to check as being one-to-one. Let $g(n)=n+1$ and $h(n)=4n$. Both $g$ and $h$ are linear functions with nonzero leading coefficient; and linear functions are one-to-one. Then $f= g\circ h$, both $g$ and $h$ are one-to-one, and a composition of one-to-one functions is also one-to-one. So $f$ is one-to-one.